# The tag "topgun-maverick" should be corrected to "top-gun-maverick"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Can someone please fix the tag [topgun-maverick](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topgun-maverick) to the correct spelling "top-gun-maverick"?

I cannot do it because when I try to replace the wrong tag with the right tag, the system refuses because the correct tag is too similar to the wrongly spelled one.